# <g:each> produces too many line breaks

Tags: grails, gsp

```
<g:each in="${users}" var="user">
${user.name}
</g:each>
```

produces

```
<br>
Bob<br>
<br>
Mike<br>
```

I never noticed this before... Any way to stop it (apart from putting the `<g:each>` and `${user.name}` lines on the same line). Is this a bug?

Comment: Is the output correct when code is in one line? If not, I guess your `user.name` already contains a linebreak.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<g:each in="${users}" var="user">${user.name}</g:each>
```

if you still get so many breaks the issue could be on the value stored in the db of ${user.name}

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem in content. Check what in `${user.name}` and try to use `${user.name.encodeAsHTML()}` and provide the result.